# $route.updateParams is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to change the route Params in my controller using the `updateParams` method, but for some reason I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: $route.updateParams is not a function.
```

In my controller I have:

```
App.controller('AddController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$route',
function ($scope, $routeParams, $route)
{
    $route.updateParams({child: 'all'});
}]);
```

And this is my routing configuration:

```
App.config([
    '$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {


    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
        .when('/:page/:child*', {
            templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
                return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page + '/' + $routeParams.child + '.html';
            },
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

}]);
```

I have no idea why can't I use the `updateParams` method, or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you added `ngRoute` as a dependency?

Comment: Of course I did. (If not, I would get an error for $route).

Comment: Oh right, misread the error.

Comment: what version of angular are you importing and what version of ng-route are you importing?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is stuck on this like I was, I had to get the 1.4.8 version of angular AND the 1.4.8 version of angular-route to use `$route.updateParams`
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jMf9Bgyw9i5c7kBd2BSk?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="routeUpdateParams">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <a href="#/test/3">Click to load the test view</a>
        <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module("routeUpdateParams", ["ngRoute"]);
 app.config(function($routeProvider ){ 
    $routeProvider.when("/test/:testId", {
        template:"<h3>test:{{testId}}</h3><button ng-click='reloadRoute()'>reloadRoute</button>",
        controller: function($scope,$route,$routeParams) {
          $scope.testId = $routeParams.testId;

          $scope.reloadRoute = function(){
            console.log($route)
            $route.updateParams({ testId: 5 });
          }
        }
    });
 });
```